# Figure object have no attribute set_title

Tags: matplotlib, figure, gplots, stem

I have used `stem_graphic` to plot a stem and leaf plot and saved it to pdf but when trying to enter title its giving error: `Figure object have no attribute set_title`.

```
ax, b=stem_graphic(mileage['disp'])
ax.set_title("Vicky")


This is the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#214>", line 1, in <module>
ax.set_title("Vicky")
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_title'
```

Answer (score 8):

It looks like your `stem_graphic` function returns a `matplotlib.figure` object, so you should use the `suptitle()` method to add a title.

try:

```
fig, b = stem_graphic(mileage['disp'])
fig.suptitle("Vicky")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `stem_graphic` function from the stemgraphic package returns a figure and an axes; the [docstring](https://github.com/fdion/stemgraphic/blob/master/stemgraphic/graphic.py) states

> :return: matplotlib figure and axes instance

The code should therefore look like

```
fig, ax =stem_graphic(mileage['disp'])
ax.set_title("Vicky")
```